# invalid target element for this operation ngTable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-9, ngtable

It's a known issue for ngTable that it can't create a header element for tables in IE 9 (and below). It creates the error

```
invalid target element for this operation
```

I just wanted to give anyone who gets this error a solution. Go to your angular.js file. Find the line that says

```
tmp.innerHTML = wrap[1] + html.replace(XHTML_TAG_REGEXP, "<$1></$2>") + wrap[2];
```

and replace it with

```
tmp.append(wrap[1] + html.replace(XHTML_TAG_REGEXP, "<$1></$2>") + wrap[2]);
```

I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere so I hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is being tracked in [github](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/issues/667). At this point there is no resolution and the suggested workaround is to use jQuery instead of angular's jqlite.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @011001000110000101110110011010 what can you do more than referencing the issue in this case ? specially if there's no resolution at this time, unfortunately SO cannot yet refresh on github issue

Comment: This perfectly answers the question. It is a known bug and there is no solution, period.